# Use Plotly and ipywidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, ipywidgets, vbox

I'm using plotly offline with ipywidgets and can't figure it out why the code below is not working:

```
op=widgets.Output()

with op:
     iplot([{"x": [1,2,3],"y": [3,1,6]}])    

box=widgets.VBox([widget1,op]
display(box)
```

If I call display(op) alone it works but I can't figure it out why the plot is not displayed when I call display(box)...

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the output of [`widget.Output()`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html) can be used only once. The code below creats a function that can be called to create output multiple times.

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output, Image
from plotly.widgets import GraphWidget
```

**Create sample dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3], 'y':[3,1,6]})
df
```

[image]

**Create function**

```
def get_out(df,xvar,yvar):
    layout={'autosize':False,'width':300,'height':300}
    op=widgets.Output()
    with op:
        w1 = df.iplot(x=xvar,y=yvar, layout=layout) 
    return op
```

**`display()` plot without box**

```
op = get_out(df,'x','y')
display(op)
```

[image]

**`display()` plot with `VBox()`**

```
# Call function 
op = get_out(df,'x','y')
widget1 = get_out(df,'y','x')
# Create box
box=widgets.VBox([widget1, op],layout={'border': '3px solid black','width':'55%'})
display(box)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it's exactly what I was looking for!